# PHP SQL Anywhere connection errors

Tags: php, linux, centos, sqlanywhere

I am having a very frustrating problem connecting to SQL Anywhere 17 from PHP 7.4.5. The OS is CentOS 7.9. I have installed the SQL Anywhere client v17. There is no Apache or web-server, PHP is in COMMAND LINE mode only!

I am explicitly loading the 64-bit extension for SQL Anywhere. "libdbcapi.so" is also loaded.
extension=/usr/include/php/ext/php-7.4.0_sqlanywhere.so ( ->  php-7.4.0_sqlanywhere.so.1)

My connection string is as follows:

```
$connString = "Uid=".$username.";Pwd=".$password.";CommLinks=tcpip(host‌​=".$server.";Port=".$port.")";
```

And I am doing the following:

```
<?php

$server = "192.168.56.105";
$port = "2638";
$username = "username";
$password = "********";

if( ! extension_loaded('sqlanywhere') ){
    print("SQL ANYWHRE not available.\n");
} else {
    print("SQL ANYWHERE extension loaded.\n");
}

$connString = "Uid=".$username.";Pwd=".$password.";CommLinks=tcpip(host‌​=".$server.";Port=".$port.")";

echo "Connecting to SQL Anywhere with: '$connString'\n";

$conn = sasql_connect($connString);

if(!$conn){
    echo "Error connecting.";
} else {
    echo "Connected.";
    sasql_disconnect($conn);
}

?>
```

I keep getting the following error though:

***PHP Warning:  sasql_connect(): SQLAnywhere: [-832] Connection error: Error in TCPIP port options in /root/scripts/bcliqx/companies_pull.php on line XX***

I have tried

```
$connString = "Uid=".$username.";Pwd=".$password.";Server=".$serverName.";host‌​=".$server.":".$port.")";
$connString = "Uid=".$username.";Pwd=".$password.";host‌​=".$server.":".$port.")";
$connString = "Uid=".$username.";Pwd=".$password.";host‌​=".$server.";port=".$port;
$connString = "Uid=".$username.";Pwd=".$password.";CommLinks=tcpip(host‌​=".$server.":".$port.")";
$connString = "Uid=".$username.";Pwd=".$password.";CommLinks=tcpip(host‌​=".$server.";Port=".$port.")";
```

And I keep getting the above error or this one:

***PHP Warning:  sasql_connect(): SQLAnywhere: [-95] Parse error: Invalid or missing keyword near 'host‌​' in /root/scripts/bcliqx/companies_pull.php on line XX***

The actual username and password contain ONLY alpha-numeric characters A-Za-z0-9 and are not very  long (8 chars, 12 chars respectively).

I am rapidly losing my sanity. What am I doing wrong?? The server is there. If I open the server & port using different tools, it answers, so connectivity is not the issue.

EDIT: Want to add that the problem happens on a cleanly installed CentOS 7.9 server as well as an older server.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us the *output* from `echo "Connecting to SQL Anywhere with: '$connString'\n";`. That is, double check that your code constructs `$connString` correctly.

Comment: It was constructing correctly. No strange characters. However, I found a/the solution. Will post in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

you need for the PHP module has a cmdline tool called dbping included.

Comment: dbping is installed.

/var/lib/pcp/pmdas/dbping, /opt/sqlanywhere17/bin64/dbping, /opt/sqlanywhere17/bin64s/dbping, /opt/sqlanywhere17/bin32/dbping, /opt/sqlanywhere17/bin32s/dbping

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The solution came from a former colleague who suggested I change the string to the following:

```
$connString = "UID=".$username.";PWD=".$password.";ENG=IQX;LINKS=tcpip(HOST=$server;DoBroadcast=NONE;PORT=$port)";
```

This works.
But this does not:

```
$connString = "UID=".$username.";PWD=".$password.";ENG=IQX;LINKS=tcpip(HOST=".$server.";DoBroadcast=NONE;PORT=$port)";
```

The second option works with a SERVERNAME as long as it contains no ".", e.g. $server = "sa17svr" will work, but $server="sa17svr.domain.com" won't.